# javascript defer property or DOM movement protocol (best practice?)

Tags: javascript

This is a general question ... with the DOM and Javascript, things get loaded top down but there are two options for loading external .js files that interrupt this. async and defer. Async I can understand but it's the defer i'm questioning. What purpose does it serve to use that option instead of just moving the script tag lower in the DOM? Is it just to keep javascript calls organized, "this .js goes with that function call" but want to keep them visually together in the code or is there another reason? I can't seem to find an explanation or an example of why the defer property would be useful.

Is it a better practice to move the script load further down the DOM or use the defer property?

This came up because I was recently debugging someone's files, they had a LOT of properties inside the script tag (bit of a mess) and couldn't figure out why function calls further down the DOM weren't working. here there was a defer property buried in all the other ones that I missed so the function wasn't defined before the call.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script is pretty clear on what it does: "This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded." which is radically different from `async` or "putting it lower in the HTML code".

Comment: according to the link it appears that defer does nothing more radical than putting it at the end of the DOM. i'm still not getting the reason behind it. Async yes is quite different :)

Comment: Just because you put it at the end of the DOM, doesn't mean another script won't inject new code that will end up _after your script_ but before DOM parsing is done, invalidating the assumption that your one (and only one, not two or more, so that's another thing) script will run _after_ the DOM has been built, but _before_ the DOMContentLoaded event gets fired off. The only way to guarantee that you really do have an "initial DOM parse complete" DOM tree, before `loaded`, is by using the defer attribute.

Comment: the benifit is when u have multile scripts to load, with async all the scripts will be executed after they loaded. with defer they are waiting for the script before was loaded.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans thank you, that throery makes more sense. Do you happen to have a quick example?